# Using array in Jenkins curl request

Tags: arrays, api, github, jenkins, curl

I have a Jenkins job (scripted pipeline) which have curl request inside "sh" block. This is an API call to Github organization, I need to use it for some repositories (about 15) in this organization. I can create 15 lines of curl requests, but I wonder if it's possible to pass repositories as arrays and add maybe a loop. Something like this:

def REPOS = ['repo1', 'repo2']
sh
"""
curl -d "mydata" -X POST 'www.website/api/{REPOS}'
"""

But I don't understand how to make it work with array and loop considering that I have Groovy + sh + curl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work for you.

```
steps {
    script {
      def repos = ['repo1', 'repo2']
      repos.each() {
      sh """ 
       echo $it
       echo "CURl here for ${it}"
       curl -d "mydata" -X POST 'https://www.website/api/${it}' 
      """
      }
    }

  }
```